# Exclude not passed fields from Pydantic 2.2

Tags: python, pydantic

Pydantic version: 2.2

I've a model:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, constr
from typing import Optional


class UpdateUserPayload(BaseModel):
    first_name: Optional[constr(min_length=1, max_length=150)]
    last_name: Optional[constr(min_length=1, max_length=150)]
    role: Optional[str]
    is_notifications: Optional[bool]
```

Now, when I try pass payload

```py
data = {"first_name": "foo"}
UpdateUserPayload(**data)
```

I get an error:

```bash
ValidationError: 3 validation errors for UpdateUserPayload
last_name
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={'first_name': 'foo'}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.2/v/missing
role
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={'first_name': 'foo'}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.2/v/missing
is_notifications
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={'first_name': 'foo'}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.2/v/missing
```

I found that Pydantic made some updates for Optional field: https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.2/migration/#required-optional-and-nullable-fields.

However, now I need Optional field to work like this:

- If Optional field not passed - ignore it (like exclude unset), I don't need None as a value of last_name, role and etc
- If Optional field passed even it was None keep this data

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Thank god they changed this in v2... Anyway, to your requirements: _"If Optional field not passed - ignore it"_ And what is supposed to happen exactly? What value should the `role` field for example hold, if you initialize a `UpdateUserPayload` instance without providing a `role` value to the constructor? I am genuinely curious what you expect to happen.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it works with exclude_unset

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, constr
from typing import Optional


class UpdateUserPayload(BaseModel):
    first_name: Optional[constr(min_length=1, max_length=150)]
    last_name: Optional[constr(min_length=1, max_length=150)]
    role: Optional[str] = None
    is_notifications: Optional[bool] = None

data = {"first_name": "foo", "last_name": "bar"}
UpdateUserPayload(**data).model_dump(exclude_unset=True)
```

As a result, I will only get first_name and last_name

Comment: But here you changed the model so that `role` and `is_notifications` both have a default value of `None`. This means the model instance you create here will have `None` as the value for those fields. Also nowhere in your question did you mention you need to dump the model. I fail to see how this relates to the requirements you laid out in your question.